# :nth-child() selector apply in specific elements

Tags: css

I want to apply the effect only on tag elements 'p'. but I have a div blocking the effect! The paragraph two must be in blue, how do?

```
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<div>The div tag.</div>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

p:nth-child(odd) { background: #ff0000; }

p:nth-child(even) { background: #0000ff; }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dt0L42v/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `:nth-of-type` selector.

```css
p:nth-of-type(odd) { background: #ff0000; }
p:nth-of-type(even) { background: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<div>The div tag.</div>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
```

Comment: ahahha nice nice ...very easy, ohh

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead.

```css
p:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
p:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<div>The div tag.</div>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-of-type() selector.</p>
```

Alternatively, Selectors L4 extends the syntax of `:nth-child()`, allowing

```css
:nth-child(odd of p)  { background: #ff0000; }
:nth-child(even of p) { background: #0000ff; }
```

... but browsers don't support it yet.